# Null-terminating changes the string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have this code that's supposed to print the first letter of a string:

```
mov bx, message   ; Move the address of the message to bx           
add bx, 0x7c00    ; Adding the padding of bootsector to bx
mov al, [bx]      ; Move the value at the address in bx to al
int 0x10          ; Interrupt drawing the character in al to screen
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
message:
    db "Test", 0
```

but this works:

```
message:
    db "Test", 0, 0
```

The first one prints some random character and the second one always the first letter of my message.

The code is compiled with NASM into .bin and ran as bootsector in Bochs.

**EDIT

full code:

```
mov ah, 0x0e

message: 
    db 'Booting MainOPS', 0

printTheMessage:
    mov bx, message
    add bx, 0x7c00
    mov al, [bx]
    int 0x10

jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: That's not a [MCVE]. Chances are you e.g. placed you string into the code path. More people do it than I would expect. Also, learn to use the bochs debugger.

Comment: @Jester I added the whole code. It basically makes no difference as it was almost my whole code. Yes anything is possible I am not a professional so it's probably something stupid. And I'm working on learning to use it.

Comment: btw, use `[org 0x7c00]` at beginning to avoid having to adjust offsets by `add bx,0x7c00` ... (but even this will work only on more common BIOSes, as some rare ones will start you not from `0000:7C00`, but something else like `07C0:0000`, so the `ds` copied from `cs` will be wrong... oh wait, you don't set up `ds` at all, that's another major problem, you are sort of lucky the bochs is so "natural" environment launching your bootloader with common-sense values in registers. Writing *ROBUST* bootloader is quite tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as @Jester guessed. You execute `message` as it was code. The code execution begins with the `mov ah, 0x0e`, then it continues with the bytes following it directly, which is the string `'Booting MainOPS', 0`, and then it follows with the `printTheMessage` code.

Either move the `message` to after the infinite loop, or add a `jmp` to `printTheMessage` after the first instruction.